# Is it possible to delete keys meeting some criterion using a simple iteration in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have a dict `d={"key1":-1,"key2":-2,"key3":3,"key4":0,"key5":-7,"key6":1,...}` in python3. Now I want to delete keys whose value is negative, e.g.,`"key1":-1`,`"key2":-2`,etc. I tried to write a code like this:

```
for k in d:
    if d[k]<0:
       del d[k]
```

But I received error saying "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration". From this message, it seems that it is not possible to delete keys of a dictionary meeting some criterion using a simple iteration, so at the moment, I have to save the keys to be deleted in a list, then write another iteration to remove them from `d`. My question is: is it really impossible to remove some of keys using a single iteration? If it's possible, could you please give a sample code of Python3 that can remove keys meeting some criterion using a simple iteration in Python3? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1: use a dictionary comprehension.  This doesn't delete so much as replace, but gets you to the same `d`.

```
>>> d = {"key1":-1,"key2":-2,"key3":3,"key4":0,"key5":-7}
>>> d = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if v >= 0}
>>> d
{'key3': 3, 'key4': 0}
```

Method #2: iterate over an independent copy of the keys:

```
>>> d = {"key1":-1,"key2":-2,"key3":3,"key4":0,"key5":-7}
>>> for k in set(d):
...     if d[k] < 0:
...         del d[k]
...         
>>> d
{'key3': 3, 'key4': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I like both of the methods!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the keys instead of the dict:

```
for k in d.keys():
    if d[k]<0:
        del d[k]
```

For this to work in Python 3.X, `keys()` returns an iterator, so you need to use the following first line:

```
for k in list(d.keys()):
```

Comment: `d.keys()` is a view over the keys, and python documentation says that **Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries**. Is your solution safe? Can you explain why?

Comment: @AkiRoss is right. This does not work in Python3.x.  I've edited the answer.